# My website uses JS link for passing a parameter, is it worth to support non JS users?

Tags: javascript, html

My website is relying heavy on javascript for the link. Passing a parameter to always know which page I started my navigation from and write it on a little navbox so the user can always go back to the starting page.

Should I bother, if javascript is disabled, to put on each link a href for a no js version and an onclik link for js?

I refrain because like this user don't know from which page he start from and the navbox appears blank.

1)If I use a js and if js is disabled rely on cookies?

2) I even have a gallery working with jquery that user can cycle through it with arrows. How can I make, if js is disabled to show instead a download link to all picture in the gallery?

Comment: I suggest you read this http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/25969/should-i-bother-to-develop-for-javascript-disabled

Comment: Depends on who your users are. Do you think they'll disable js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I bother, if `JavaScript` is disabled, to put on each link a `href` for a no `JS` version and an `onClik` link for `JS`?

Why not use a main navigation for your pages? That way, from any page, you can go to any page.

There's always the back and forward buttons to move forward and... back. Never underestimate these two buttons. People do use them.

> If I use a `JS`and if `JS` is disabled rely on cookies?

Refer to the paragraph above, and you won't even need cookies or even `JS` for navigation.

> How can I make, if `JS` is disabled to show instead a download link to all picture in the gallery?

There's the `<noscript>` for that:

```
<noscript><a href="path/to/pictures">Download</a></noscript>
```

Comment: I am using:
 <script>
  document.getElementById('hasJavaScript').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('noscript').style.display = 'none';


</script>
this, hiding the hasjavasript with display:none.

because i want to hide the jquery gallery

And last question: It's ok to put script at the end of the page, because if i put in the head, it doesn't work sometimes.

Comment: @user2748576 You can have that block initially hidden by CSS. If JS is available, changing the `display` to `block` via JS would do. If JS isn't available, it remains hidden, no additional work needed. And yes, `<script>` are much preferred just before `</body>`

Comment: Actually i have to: NO JS: hide gallery and show image, JS: hide image and show gallery.
Is my solution ok?